# Matrix obtained by basis of polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, interpolation

Consider the matrix $V$ given by

$$ V = \phi_k(z_j) $$

with $\phi_0, \dots, \phi_n$ a basis for the space of polynomials of degree $n$ and $z_0, \dots, z_n$ pairwise distinct points. A basis is the following: ${1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n}$. Is the resulting matrix a Vandermonde matrix? The problem I am asked to solve is the following: is it true that, if the points are pairwise distinct, this generalized Vandermonde matrix is invertible (given $\phi_0, \dots, \phi_n$ a basis for the space of polynomials of degree $n$)? Do I have to consider a more *general* basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\psi_0,...,\psi_n$ and $\varphi_0,...,\varphi_n$ are two bases for the same space, then there is an invertible matrix $g\in GL_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g\bar {\varphi}=\bar{\psi }$. It then follows that $det(\psi_k (z_i))=\det(g)\det(\varphi_k(z_i))$, so that the first is invertible iff the second is invertible. Since you already know a basis for which this matrix is invertible (e.g. $1,x,...,x^n$, or even better construct polynomials $\varphi_i$ such that $\varphi_i(z_j)=\delta_{i,j}$), then for every basis of polynomials this matrix is invertible.

**EDIT**:

Some Examples: If we take the basis $1,x,x^2$, then the matrix we get is

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1\\
z_{1} & z_{2} & z_{3}\\
z_{1}^{2} & z_{2}^{2} & z_{3}^{2}
\end{array}\right)$$
which is a Vandermonde matrix and therefore invertible. We can also choose the basis 
$$f_1(x)=\frac{(x-z_2)(x-z_3)}{(z_1-z_2)(z_1-z_3)}, f_2(x)=\frac{(x-z_1)(x-z_3)}{(z_2-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}, f_3(x)=\frac{(x-z_1)(x-z_2)}{(z_3-z_1)(z_3-z_2)}$$
and then the matrix will be the identity matrix.

Finally, let's take the basis $1,1+x,1+x+x^2$ which can be written as
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1+x\\
1+x+x^2
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
x\\
x^2
\end{array}\right)$$
Then the matrix is 
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1+z_{1} & 1+z_{2} & 1+z_{3}\\
1+z_1+z_{1}^{2} & 1+z_2+z_{2}^{2} & 1+z_3z_{3}^{2}
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1\\
z_{1} & z_{2} & z_{3}\\
z_{1}^{2} & z_{2}^{2} & z_{3}^{2}
\end{array}\right)
$$
Because the Vandermonde matrix is invertible, and we multiply it by an invertible matrix, then the new matrix is also invertible.

Comment: could you please exaplain better the second part (from "Since...")? Thanks.

Comment: Moreover, considering your first assertion, does it have a name (theorem, proposition, lemma...) since I would like to study the proof. Thanks.

Comment: @LorenzoFabbri I doubt if this result has a name attached to it since it is very simple. The fact that you can move between any two bases by an invertible matrix is basic linear algebra and the equality of determinants follows directly from the definition of the matrix. Regarding the second part, the basis $1,x,...,x^n$ simply gives you a Vandermonde matrix which is invertible. The second basis gives you the identity matrix which is obviously invertible (for more details, see for example Lagrange interpolation polynomials)

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not see it. I do not follow your "first", "this matrix"... I cannot understand what are you talking about. We take $\phi_0, \dots, \phi_n$ to be the basis $1,x,\dots,x^n$ and then? Why the second basis gives the identity matrix? Thank you.

Comment: Is it because it's a change of basis matrix ($g$)?

Comment: @LorenzoFabbri added some examples